# django runserver works, but with daphne there's an error

Tags: python, django, django-channels, daphne

I have a django website with channels for websockets that is working on my local machine. I can call `python manage.py runserver` and the site runs fine, the frontend websocket connection can send and receive from the backend server. However, when I wrap the django code in a daphne call, it throws an error:

`daphne -b 0.0.0.0 backend.app_proj.asgi:application`

```
File "c:\projects\injurycheck\v1\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "c:\projects\injurycheck\v1\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
File "c:\projects\injurycheck\v1\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create module = import_module(entry)
File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pipeline'
```

Can anyone say why the site builds correctly under runserver, but inside daphne it can't find an app that is actually included in INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: were is your `manage.py` located, and where is the 'pipeline' module relative to it, this looks like an issue with your python path.

Comment: @MatthausWoolard file structure is:
backend/manage.py
backend/app_proj/settings.py
backend/app_proj/asgi.py
backend/pipeline/consumers.py

Comment: Same Issue on Debian 10. I have No module named 'whitenoise' as error message.

Answer (score 1):

```
cd /path/to/your/project
daphne -b 0.0.0.0 app_proj.asgi:application
```

show my backend server with nginx command:

```
cd /path/to/your/project
daphne -b 127.0.0.1 -p 8080 -e ssl:8443:privateKey=/path/to/privkey.pem:certKey=/path/to/fullchain.pem app.asgi:application -v 3
```

Comment: I said nothing about using nginx.